# Nginx variable names are lost between OpenResty captures

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

When creating a variable from the server_name in Nginx and calling a different endpoint using ngx.location.capture the variable is then gone.

The following example demonstrates by calling testlocalhost and acclocalhost:

```
server {
    listen 1003;
    server_name ~^(?<name>test|acc)localhost$; #<-Name is set here

    location / {
        #return 200 $name; #This would return the expected test or acc
        content_by_lua 'local options = {
                            method = ngx.HTTP_GET,
                        }
                        local res = ngx.location.capture("/internal", options)
                        ngx.say(res.body)';
    }

    location /internal {   
        return 200 $name; #<- Name is empty here
    }
}
```

Is there any way to maintain the variable between endpoints without modifying the body or using url parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add to the option to ngx.location.capture to share or copy all available variables.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture

> ***copy_all_vars*** specify whether to copy over all the Nginx variable
>   values of the current request to the subrequest in question.
>   modifications of the nginx variables in the subrequest will not affect
>   the current (parent) request. This option was first introduced in the
>   v0.3.1rc31 release.
>
> ***share_all_vars*** specify whether to share all the Nginx variables of the
>   subrequest with the current (parent) request. modifications of the
>   Nginx variables in the subrequest will affect the current (parent)
>   request. Enabling this option may lead to hard-to-debug issues due to
>   bad side-effects and is considered bad and harmful. Only enable this
>   option when you completely know what you are doing.

```
    location / {
        #return 200 $name; #This would return the expected test or acc
        content_by_lua 'local options = {
                            method = ngx.HTTP_GET,
                            share_all_vars = true
                        }
                        local res = ngx.location.capture("/internal", options)
                        ngx.say(res.body)';
    }
```